# how to add two onClick functions in React

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, onclick, google-tag-manager

hey ~ I'm trying to fire a submit function and a google click event on the same onClick in React. How do I do this in React?

This is the code:

```
<button className={s.button} onClick={this.submit} onClick={ () => {gaClickEvent('where-to-buy', 'submit' , undefined)}}>
```

Comment: why not call the second onClick on the first one?

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways of doing this.

To start with, you can put two statements in the click handler that you're defining inline with the ES6 function literal syntax.

```
<button 
  className={s.button}
  onClick={ (e) => {
    gaClickEvent('home-where-to-buy', 'submit' , undefined);
    this.submit(e);
  }} >
```

But this is slightly more code that I'd be comfortable putting in an onClick handler. If I were you, I'd separate this logic out into a handler method on the component. Eg:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick () {
    gaClickEvent('home-where-to-buy', 'submit' , undefined);
    this.submit();
  },
  render () {
    return <button 
      className={s.button}
      onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} >
      I am a button!
      </button>;
  }
})
```

Comment: hi thanks for responding. I tried your first method, but it doesn't submit the form. Instead it throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Comment: This is the submit function                                                                `submit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.refs.input.value.length === 5) {
      this.context.router.push('/where-to-buy/?zip=' + this.refs.input.value);
    }
  }`

Comment: I've changed my answer so it should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
class Mycomponent extends React.component {
 submit(e) {
  //handle event
 }
 render() {
  return <button className={s.button} onClick={this.submit.bind(this)} />
 }
}
```